# SLIM add space at start of multi line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I am trying to add a space to the start of my slim template where I have had to break the text due to a link, I cant for the life of me work this one out

```
.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--4-col-phone.mdl-cell--8-col-tablet.mdl-cell--12-col-desktop
  | Don't have an account?
  = link_to 'Create one here.', sign_up_path
```

Comment: You want to insert space before .mdl-cell div?

Comment: no before the Create One here so that the text will be in 1 line "Don't have an account? Create one here"

Comment: Can you put the required html, then I may give it a try?

Comment: Try ' on new line between | Don't have an account? and = link_to

Answer (score 20, accepted):

found after some deeper research that the slim way is to use `>` so the new code is, which forced whitespace at the end of the first line

```
span> Don't have an account? 
= link_to 'Create one here.', sign_up_path
```

Comment: 'Deeper'? This is like one of the first things you will see on Slim's Github readme :D

Comment: maybe it is now 3 years after the question was raised

Comment: Sorry, I was probably in a snarky mood when I commented back in 2017 :/ Thanks for spreading the knowledge 

Comment: You can also do `=< link_to ...`. `<` and/or `>` can be added to tags or `=` to add space before and/or after the content.

Answer (score 13):

with a simple quote ' the slim add a space

```
.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--4-col-phone.mdl-cell--8-col-tablet.mdl-cell--12-col-desktop
  | Don't have an account?
  '
  = link_to 'Create one here.', sign_up_path
```

Comment: ended up adding span in front of the first line with `>`

Comment: I fix my code now. But you have tried with this code?

Comment: this also worked seems we have 3 ways of solving the problem, none of which reduce the amount of code

Comment: It seems so. I use this way because saw it in the slim doc http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Verbatim_text_with_trailing_white_space__

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&nbsp;` to add space between html elements:

```
.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--4-col-phone.mdl-cell--8-col-tablet.mdl-cell--12-col-desktop
| Don't have an account?&nbsp;
= link_to 'Create one here.', sign_up_path
```

Comment: this is a bit messy, isnt their a more elegant way of achieving this

Comment: You need `|\&nbsp;` instead of `|&nbsp;`

Comment: this just seems so messy, and i thought the purpose of slim was to reduce the number of lines of code. this now makes this file more lines than haml for the same code

Comment: @ArupRakshit Why backslash is needed? I always use |&nbsp;

You can attach &nbsp; at the end of text: "Don't have an account?&nbsp;". I looking for another solution when I started with Slim, but I found nothing.

Comment: after a few hours googling, another method i came across was `span> Don't have an account?
      = link_to 'Create one here.', sign_up_path`

Comment: I have had the same problems. I am glad this question was asked. I crigne everytime I have to deal with spaces in slim. Apparently there is a git issue thread on this, they keep adding this space fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a space after `| Don't have an account?`, it will be honored. Perhaps your text editor is set to remove all trailing whitespace.

If that's the case, then the cleanest approach is to simply use `| Don't have an account?&nbsp;`.